# How to have a separate CSS variable for each React component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a component that I want to be able to use multiple times but have some of the CSS be different based props passed in. The problem is doing the way that I have changes it across all of my component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Gauge(props) {
    useEffect(() =>{
        getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--fillColor');
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--fillColor', props.color);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="gauge">
             <div className="gaugeFill"></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
.gaugeFill {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: var(--fillColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that easiest solution is to set that css variable(if you want is as var()) in inline style

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Gauge(props) {
    return (
        <div className="gauge" style={{ "--fill-color": props.color } as React.CSSProperties}>
             <div className="gaugeFill"  ></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

otherwise you can just set color in `gaugeFill`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function Gauge(props) {
    return (
        <div className="gauge">
             <div className="gaugeFill" style={{background: props.color}}  ></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```